# Postfix - MX: Host not found error but dig and nslookup are OK

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, postfix, centos7, mx-record

I had a working `Postfix` email server on `Centos 7` when I decided to reconfigure my host networking (IP addressing, DNS, etc.), after reconfiguration, mail sending is no longer working.

`/var/log/maillog`:

```
Dec  7 10:20:03 server postfix/error[1711]: 030763B26: to=<gmailaccount@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.08/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=domain.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

I am pretty sure Postfix user's MX lookups work:

```
[lester@server ~]$ sudo -u postfix -H cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
[lester@server ~]$
[lester@server ~]$ sudo -u postfix -H dig gmail.com MX

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> gmail.com MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56702
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.      3158    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3158    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3158    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3158    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3158    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 07 10:27:03 EST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 161

[lester@server ~]$
```

I feel like I am missing something very obvious here. I have been searching hours but all the references I find point to Postfix being unable to perform MX lookups.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered this host had `selinux` enabled, so I digged in the audit logs and viola!

`/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1575731823.372:174): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1613 comm="smtp" name="resolv.conf" dev="vda1" ino=28066 scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_smtp_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Check the selinux context of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
[lester@server ~]$ ls -lZ /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 /etc/resolv.conf
[lester@server ~]$
```

Restore selinux context:

```
[lester@server ~]$ sudo restorecon /etc/resolv.conf
[lester@server ~]$ ls -lZ /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:net_conf_t:s0  /etc/resolv.conf
[lester@server ~]$
```

Restart `Postfix`:

```
[lester@server ~]$ sudo systemctl restart postfix
[lester@server ~]$
```

All back to normal.